working with several tikz forest
EDIT: ultimately my problem was how to have several trees in one single tikzpicture and being able to access node positions. See the accepted answer for how to do that. My workaround caused the initial issue with bold text, with a clean picture it vanishes.
I want to draw a TikZ picture containing a forest that include bold text. For some reason, I cannot use \textbf, \textit or \texttt inside the tree:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{forest}
     begin draw/.code={},end draw/.code={},
     tikz={\node[fit to=tree] {};},
        for tree={
            math content,       % direct math environment, no $
            calign=fixed edge angles,  % keep straight line with tier
            calign primary angle=-35,calign secondary angle=35,   % angle between 2 children
        }
        [\textbf{1} \oplus \textbf{3}, name=top,
            [ \textbf{2}, name=dim1]
            [ \textbf{2}, name=dim2]
        ]
\end{forest}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I get the same error with both pdflatex and lualatex:
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000]. \end{forest}

This happens when mixing TikZ, forest and \textbf. Other combinations work fine:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}   % without tikz, this is fine
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
        for tree={
            math content,       % direct math environment, no $
            calign=fixed edge angles,  % keep straight line with tier
            calign primary angle=-35,calign secondary angle=35,   % angle between 2 children
        }
        [\textbf{1} \oplus \textbf{3}, name=top,
            [ \textbf{2}, name=dim1]
            [ \textbf{2}, name=dim2]
        ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}  % using depreciated \bf is fine
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{forest}
     begin draw/.code={},end draw/.code={},
     tikz={\node[fit to=tree] {};},
        for tree={
            math content,       % direct math environment, no $
            calign=fixed edge angles,  % keep straight line with tier
            calign primary angle=-35,calign secondary angle=35,   % angle between 2 children
        }
        [\bf 1 \oplus \bf 3, name=top,
            [ \bf 2, name=dim1]
            [ \bf 2, name=dim2]
        ]
\end{forest}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Is this a bug in the package forest? Is there a way to fix it with a package option? Using \bf as a workaround oviously works, but I also have issues with \texttt, for some reason \tt refuses to work outside of math mode.
EDIT: since people are curious about the use case, here is the main picture. It is more complex, with several trees involved (I could use only 2 trees instead of 4)
\documentclass{standalone}

\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \def \leveldistance{1cm}   % distance between 2 tree levels
    \def \innersep{0.4mm}      % space around node in tree
    \def \treeangle{35}        % angle below a tree node
    \def \yshift_sing{0.5cm};  % distance between tree top and bond between them
    \tikzset{
        e1/.style={line width=0.3mm,inner sep=0.4mm},
        e2/.style={line width=0.4mm,inner sep=0.6mm},
        inv/.style={draw=none,},
    }
            \begin{scope}[xshift=3.4cm] 
            \begin{forest}  % for some reason \textbf fails inside the forest
                begin draw/.code={},end draw/.code={},
                tikz={\node[fit to=tree](oldtree) {};},
                for tree={
                    grow=south,
                    edge=e1,
                    inner sep=\innersep,  % empty space around node
                    l=\leveldistance,     % level distance
                    math content,         % direct math environment, no $
                    calign=fixed edge angles,  % keep straight line with tier
                    calign primary angle=-\treeangle,calign secondary angle=\treeangle,   % angle between 2 children
                }
                [{\bf 2},name=newDO,
                    [ 2\cdot{\bf 2}, name=newdotop, tier=4
                        [{\bf 1}\oplus {\bf 3}, name=xnewdostruct, tier=5
                            [{\bf 2},tier=6, name=new1,
                                []
                            ]
                            [{\bf 2}, tier=6,name=new2,
                                []
                            ]
                        ]
                        [{\bf 2}, tier=6, name=new3,
                                []
                        ]
                    ]
                    [,edge=inv]
                ]
            \end{forest}
            
            \begin{scope}[xshift=4.4cm]
                \begin{forest}  % for some reason \textbf fails inside the forest
                    begin draw/.code={},end draw/.code={},
                    tikz={\node[fit to=tree](oldtree) {};},
                    for tree={
                        grow=south,
                        edge=e1,
                        inner sep=\innersep,  % empty space around node
                        l=\leveldistance,     % level distance
                        math content,         % direct math environment, no $
                        calign=fixed edge angles,  % keep straight line with tier
                        calign primary angle=-\treeangle,calign secondary angle=\treeangle,   % angle between 2 children
                    }
                    [{\bf 2},name=newCO,
                        [1\cdot{\bf 2}, name=newcotop, tier=4,
                            [\phantom{{\bf 1}\oplus {\bf 3}}, name=xnewcostruct, parent anchor=center, child anchor=center
                                [{\bf 2}, name=new4, tier=6,
                                    []
                                ]
                                [, tier=6, edge=inv, child anchor=center,parent anchor=center,]
                            ]
                            [,edge=inv,parent anchor=center, child anchor=center]
                        ]
                        [,edge=inv]
                    ]
                \end{forest}
    
    
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-7.6cm, xshift=0cm]
        \begin{forest}  % for some reason \textbf fails inside the forest
                begin draw/.code={},end draw/.code={},
                tikz={\node[fit to=tree] {};},
                for tree={
                    grow=north,
                    edge=e1,
                    inner sep=\innersep,  % empty space around node
                    l=\leveldistance,     % level distance
                    math content,         % direct math environment, no $
                    calign=fixed edge angles,  % keep straight line with tier
                    calign primary angle=-\treeangle,calign secondary angle=\treeangle,   % angle between 2 children
                }
                [{\bf 3},name=DO,
                    [\phantom{1+3}, edge=inv]
                    [1\cdot{\bf 3}, name=dotop,
                        [\phantom{1}, edge=inv]
                        [{\bf 1} \oplus {\bf 3}, name=xolddostruct,
                            [{\bf 2}, name=old2,
                                    []
                            ]
                            [{\bf 2}, name=old1,
                                []
                            ]
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            \end{forest}
            
            \begin{scope}[xshift=3.4cm]
                \begin{forest}
                    begin draw/.code={},end draw/.code={},
                    tikz={\node[fit to=tree] {};},
                    for tree={
                        grow=north,
                        edge=e1,
                        inner sep=\innersep,  % empty space around node
                        l=\leveldistance,     % level distance
                        math content,         % direct math environment, no $
                        calign=fixed edge angles,  % keep straight line with tier
                        calign primary angle=-\treeangle,calign secondary angle=\treeangle,   % angle between 2 children
                    }
                    [{\bf 3},name=CO,
                        [\phantom{1+3}, edge=inv]
                        [1\cdot{\bf 3}, name=cotop,
                            [\phantom{1}, edge=inv]
                            [{\bf 1} \oplus {\bf 3}, name=xoldcostruct,
                                [{\bf 2}, name=old4,
                                        []
                                ]
                                [{\bf 2}, name=old3,
                                    []
                                ]
                            ],
                        ]
                    ]
                \end{forest}
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
    
    % merge new codomain and domain trees
    \coordinate (topmid) at ($(newCO)!0.5!(newDO)$);
    \node [] (top1) at  ($(topmid) + (0, 2*\yshift_sing)$) {\textbf{1}};
    \draw[style=e1]  (newCO) -- ($(newCO) + (0,\yshift_sing)$) -- ($(newDO) + (0,\yshift_sing)$) -- (newDO);
    \draw[style=e1]  ($(topmid) + (0, \yshift_sing)$) -- (top1);
    \draw[style=e1, dotted]  (top1) -- ($(top1) + (0, \yshift_sing)$);
    
    % merge old codomain and domain trees
    \coordinate (downmid) at ($(CO)!0.5!(DO)$);
    \node [] (down1) at  ($(downmid) - (0, 2*\yshift_sing)$) {\textbf{1}};
    \draw[style=e1]  (CO) -- ($(CO) - (0,\yshift_sing)$) -- ($(DO) - (0,\yshift_sing)$) -- (DO);
    \draw[style=e1]  ($(downmid) - (0, \yshift_sing)$) -- (down1);
    \draw[style=e1, dotted]  (down1) -- ($(down1) - (0, \yshift_sing)$);
    
    % add old structural multiplicities
    \node[style=e1] (dostruct) at ($(CO-|xolddostruct)$)  {\color{yellow} 1};
    \node[style=e1] (costruct) at ($(CO-|xoldcostruct)$)  {\color{SpringGreen} 1};
    \draw[style=e1]  (costruct) -- (cotop);
    \draw[style=e1]  (dostruct) -- (dotop);
    
    % add new structural multiplicities
    \node[style=e1] (newdostruct) at ($(newDO-|xnewdostruct)$)  {\color{Green} 2};
    \node[style=e1] (newcostruct) at ($(newCO-|xnewcostruct)$)  {\color{red} 1};
    \draw[style=e1]  (newcostruct) -- (newcotop);
    \draw[style=e1]  (newdostruct) -- (newdotop);
    
    % add permutation box
    \coordinate (mid) at ($(old4)!0.5!(new1)$);
    \node[
    rectangle, draw=black, fill=white, line width=0.2mm, minimum width=5.6cm, minimum height=0.6cm, align=center,
    ] (P) at (mid) {\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont perm $((4,1,3),(2,))$};
    
    \node[style=e2, scale=0.6]  at ($(newdotop) + (0.6, 0)$) {$ \color{Gray}[\oplus \textbf{4} ]$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE! I can't reproduce your problem. Forest diagram works also in tikzpicture environment. However, I wonder why you like to insert forest in tikzpicture? What benefits you expect with doing this?

@Zarko I can reproduce,

@DavidCarlisle, interesting. I tested code with recent MiKTeX (I suppose that it contain recent version of all packages involved in OP code). However, between your MWE and OP MWE is seems to be important diference: OP use \bf instruction meanwhile you use \textbf{...}. With use of later, I reproduce error too.

The case where you don't load tikz is not really without it since forest obviously loads it anyway .... Are you trying to include multiple forests into a single tikzpicture? That's the only reason I can think to try the code you've got?

Indeed, I have several forests in my tikzpicture, including some with different grow directions.

@OlivierGauthé That requires a different solution. Can you edit to provide an example with a second tree?

I added the main picture.

Edit
Here's a way to draw your actual trees using the general method explained in my original answer (below).
Keeping track of positions within the trees is complex, so we define a couple of styles to help.

tree quartet={<growth direction>}{<name>} is just a convenience wrapper to avoid duplicating code, except that <name> is used to save the x coordinate of the tree's bounding box at the end. I used A, B, C and D which saves the coordinates as \Apointx, \Bpointx, \Cpointx and \DpointX.
add me={<text>}{<colour>} is used to add in the additional constructs which saves having to position them later.
save x=\macroname saves the current node's x coordinate into \macroname. I used \apointx, \bpointx, \cpointx and \dpointx.

Once the boxes are unpacked into nodes A, B, C and D, we can then calculate the x coordinates of their roots using the north east anchor of the node and the values of \Apointx and \apointx. (We could actually omit save x here as we're dealing with root notes so the value is always zero, but this might be wanted for a non-root, so we keep a more general structure. You can delete this if you only care about roots.)
Then AX, BX, CX and DX are used to name coordinates which correspond to the roots' outside borders e.g. north or south. (You might want to adjust the value you use to yshift the top/bottom points because we're not starting from the centre.
I also removed stray characters from your input.
\documentclass{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/723017/ addaswyd o gwesitwn Olivier Gauthé: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/723014/
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\forestset{%
  tree quartet/.style 2 args={%
    for tree={
      grow=#1,
      edge=e1,
      inner sep=0.4mm,  
      l'=1cm,     
      math content,         
      calign=fixed edge angles,  
      calign primary angle'=-35,
      calign secondary angle'=35,
    },
    tikz+={%
      \path (current bounding box.east);
      \pgfgetlastxy{\tempx}{\tempy}%
      \expandafter\xdef\csname #2pointx\endcsname{\tempx}%
    },
  },
  add me/.style 2 args={%
    tikz+/.process={Ow{edge}{%
        \node (a) [anchor=center,#2] at ({$(!u)+2*(|- !u)$} |- !u) {$\textbf{#1}$}; 
        \draw [##1] () -- (a);  
      }%
    },
  },
  save x/.style={%
    before drawing tree={%
      TeX={\xdef#1{\foresteoption{x}}}%
    },
  },
}
\tikzset{
  e1/.style={line width=0.3mm,inner sep=0.4mm},
  e2/.style={line width=0.4mm,inner sep=0.6mm},
  inv/.style={draw=none,},
}
\newbox\treeboxa
\newbox\treeboxb
\newbox\treeboxc
\newbox\treeboxd
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}  % for some reason \textbf fails inside the forest
    tree quartet={south}{A},
    draw tree box=\treeboxa,
    [\textbf{2},save x=\apointx
      [ 2\cdot\textbf{2},  tier=4, label={[e2,gray,font=\scriptsize]right:{$[\oplus \textbf{4}]$}}, add me={2}{green}
            [\textbf{1}\oplus \textbf{3}, tier=5
                [\textbf{2},tier=6, name=new1,
                    []
                ]
                [\textbf{2}, tier=6,name=new2,
                    []
                ]
            ]
            [\textbf{2}, tier=6, name=new3,
                    []
            ]
        ]
        [,edge=inv]
    ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}  % for some reason \textbf fails inside the forest
  tree quartet={south}{B},
  draw tree box=\treeboxb,
  [\textbf{2},save x=\bpointx
    [1\cdot\textbf{2},  tier=4, add me={1}{red}
            [\phantom{\textbf{1}\oplus \textbf{3}},  parent anchor=center, child anchor=center
                [\textbf{2},  tier=6,
                    []
                ]
                [, tier=6, edge=inv, child anchor=center,parent anchor=center,]
            ]
            [,edge=inv,parent anchor=center, child anchor=center]
        ]
        [,edge=inv]
    ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}  % for some reason \textbf fails inside the forest
    tree quartet={north}{C},
    draw tree box=\treeboxc
    [\textbf{3},save x=\cpointx
        [\phantom{1+3}, edge=inv]
        [1\cdot\textbf{3},  add me={1}{yellow}
            [\phantom{1}, edge=inv]
            [\textbf{1} \oplus \textbf{3}, 
                [\textbf{2}, 
                        []
                ]
                [\textbf{2}, 
                    []
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
    tree quartet={north}{D},
    draw tree box=\treeboxd,
    [\textbf{3},save x=\dpointx
        [\phantom{1+3}, edge=inv]
        [1\cdot\textbf{3}, add me={1}{SpringGreen}
            [\phantom{1}, edge=inv]
            [\textbf{1} \oplus \textbf{3}, 
                [\textbf{2}, 
                        []
                ]
                [\textbf{2}, 
                    []
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}            
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \def \yshift_sing{0.5cm}  % distance between tree top and bond between them
    \node [inner sep=-.2mm] (A) {\usebox\treeboxa};
    \node [anchor=north west,inner sep=-.2mm] (C) at (A.south west) {\usebox\treeboxc};
    \node [anchor=north west,inner sep=-.2mm] (D) at (A.south east) {\usebox\treeboxd};
    \node [anchor=south west,inner sep=-.2mm] (B) at (A.south east) {\usebox\treeboxb};
    % merge new codomain and domain trees
    \path (A.north east) ++({-\Apointx+\apointx},0pt) coordinate (AX);
    \path (B.north east) ++({-\Bpointx+\bpointx},0pt) coordinate (BX);
    \path (C.south east) ++({-\Cpointx+\cpointx},0pt) coordinate (CX);
    \path (D.south east) ++({-\Dpointx+\dpointx},0pt) coordinate (DX);
    \coordinate (topmid) at ($(AX)!0.5!(BX)$);
    \coordinate (top1) at  ($(topmid) + (0, \yshift_sing)$);
    \draw[e1]  (AX) -- ($(AX) + (0,\yshift_sing)$) -- ($(BX) + (0,\yshift_sing)$) -- (BX);
    \draw[e1]  ($(topmid) + (0, \yshift_sing)$) -- (top1);
    \draw[e1, dotted]  (top1) -- ($(top1) + (0, \yshift_sing)$) node [anchor=south] {\textbf{1}};
    
    % merge old codomain and domain trees
    \coordinate (downmid) at ($(CX)!0.5!(DX)$);
    \coordinate (down1) at  ($(downmid) - (0, \yshift_sing)$);
    \draw[e1]  (CX) -- ($(CX) - (0,\yshift_sing)$) -- ($(DX) - (0,\yshift_sing)$) -- (DX);
    \draw[e1]  ($(downmid) - (0, \yshift_sing)$) -- (down1);
    \draw[e1, dotted]  (down1) -- ($(down1) - (0, \yshift_sing)$) node [anchor=north] {\textbf{1}};
        
    \node[
    rectangle, draw=black, fill=white, line width=0.2mm, minimum width=5.6cm, minimum height=0.6cm, align=center, anchor=west, xshift=-2.5mm
    ] (P) at (A.south west) {\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont perm $((4,1,3),(2,))$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Original answer
forest's parser is not designed to work inside a tikzpicture environment, where many of the usual rules do not apply. In particular, trying to measure the width of text, for example, fails inside a tikzpicture unless one temporarily suspends the environment.
I do not recommend 'solving' this by overriding tikzpicture's setting of the font to the null font. A tikzpicture changes lots of other things, too, and changing the font outside nodes may well have unintended consequences as well.
There are various ways to accommodate multiple trees within a single tikzpicture. For example, in some cases a phantom root node can render the same result as a single tree. Since I don't know what your trees look like, I don't know how easy that would be to implement.
Fortunately, we can use a built-in forest solution and a couple of boxes.
Strategy:

If you want n trees in a single picture, create n-1 TeX boxes.

If you have very many, this might be a problem, but you would need a very large page or very small trees. In that case, you could juggle them to use only two or three boxes, but it would be more complex.
In reality, I assume this is a non-issue.



\newbox\treeboxa
\newbox\treeboxb


Specify n-1 forest environments for n-1 of the trees. In the preamble of each add

baseline,
draw tree box=<name of TeX box>,


Construct the nth tree in another forest environment and place each of the other trees in a node.

This allows you a great deal of flexibility over placement etc.
The idea of issuing baseline for each tree is to make it easy to align them. You may not want this, though, or you'd probably not be trying to combine them in the first place.



baseline,

For example,
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\newbox\treeboxa
\newbox\treeboxb
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
 baseline,
 draw tree box=\treeboxa,
 for tree={
   math content,       % direct math environment, no $
   calign=fixed edge angles,  % keep straight line with tier
   calign primary angle=-35,calign secondary angle=35,   % angle between 2 children
 }
  [\textbf{1} \oplus \textbf{3}, name=top,
      [ \textbf{2}, name=dim1]
      [ \textbf{2}, name=dim2]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
 baseline,
 draw tree box=\treeboxb,
 for tree={
   grow'=90,
   math content,       % direct math environment, no $
   calign=fixed edge angles,  % keep straight line with tier
   calign primary angle=-35,calign secondary angle=35,   % angle between 2 children
 }
  [\textbf{1} \oplus \textbf{3}, name=top,
      [ \textbf{2}, name=dim1]
      [ \textbf{2}, name=dim2]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  baseline,
  for tree={
    grow'=135,
    math content,       % direct math environment, no $
    calign=fixed edge angles,  % keep straight line with tier
    calign primary angle=-35,calign secondary angle=35,   % angle between 2 children
  }
  [\textbf{1} \oplus \textbf{3}, name=top,
    [ \textbf{2}, name=dim1]
    [ \textbf{2}, name=dim2]
  ]
  \node [anchor=base east] at (current bounding box.base west) {\usebox\treeboxb};
  \node [anchor=base east] at (current bounding box.base west) {\usebox\treeboxa};
\end{forest}
\end{document}



Thanks for the detailed answer. My main issue was drawing several forest while precisely positioning their root, then adding other elements in the picture. I will give a try to your solution.

@OlivierGauthé Please see edit above. Keeping track of the root makes it a bit more complicated, so I defined a couple of styles to help.

Wow thank you! This is the solution I have been looking for in order when working with several trees :)

@OlivierGauthé This was an interesting problem as I've not done anything quite like this before. (And more tractable than trying to keep track in more complex scenarios.)


It defines selectfont to be an infinite loop, not sure why.
This breaks the cycle
\documentclass{standalone}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{forest}
\let\pgf@selectfont\selectfont
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{forest}
     begin draw/.code={},end draw/.code={},
     tikz={\node[fit to=tree] {};},
        for tree={
            math content,       % direct math environment, no $
            calign=fixed edge angles,  % keep straight line with tier
            calign primary angle=-35,calign secondary angle=35,   % angle between 2 children
        }
        [\textbf{1} \oplus \textbf{3}, name=top,
            [ \textbf{2}, name=dim1]
            [ \textbf{2}, name=dim2]
        ]
\end{forest}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thank you! Do I understand correctly that you force selectfont to call the lower level version from pgf?

I hesitate to say this to you of all people, but I don't think this is a good solution.

@OlivierGauthé No, he's overriding the method tikz uses to void text within tikzpicture environments. I do not recommend this because this answer leaves you with the basic issue in your code unresolved: namely that you are making forest parse the specification of your tree within the tikzpicture environment. That is not how forest is designed to work.

@cfr yes it was really just the first stage of isolating where the loop was, but since the example worked and it was late, I posted and went to bed:-)  Olivier if you unaccept this I could delete it and leave cfr's answer visible

Well, I suspect you would at least have to ping, but you have the tick and 4 votes, so I don't think there's much to say here. ;)

@cfr the votes aren't an issue but the tick blocks deletion (I thought that the OP got pinged on all comments on their own question, but my experience of questions isn't great, i'll ping in case...)

@OlivierGauthé ping ^^^ :-)

I think that only applied to comments on the question and you got pinged for comments on your answer. & yes, I know a tick blocks deletion because I've tried it ;).

@OlivierGauthé in answer to your first comment, I didn't really consider it in terms of what it was doing,, I just traced the error message which occurs because something was redefining \pgf@selectfont to expand to itself, so creating an infinite loop leading to the memory overflow you showed. So as a more or less first try, without looking at the package code at all, I simplified (or at  least changed)  the original definition of \pgf@selectfont then the loop was avoided, and the output looked about right so I called it done.

So I removed the tick, but I think you should not delete the comment as the discussion is interesting.

@OlivierGauthé oh OK I'll leave it here but at least cfr's will get listed first which is probably a good thing.
